# How to display an array in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display an array as a list in Angular 5 but my way didn't worked

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li  *ngFor="let Flowwer of FlowwersBy" class="list-group-item" >
      {{ Flowwer }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and from where the array gets the values

```
ngOnInit() {

    // Once component loads, get user's data to display on profile
      this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.FlowwersBy = profile.user.FlowwersBy;
    });
  }
```

Comment: you sure FlowwersBy is not empty ? Otherwise this should work.

Comment: its not empty it get it's value from the DB

Comment: why is flowers spelled incorrectly?

Comment: did you check your array elements by using console.log()

Comment: post your ts code please.

Comment: I checked it and it does have the values but it seems there is something wrong

Comment: What does `console.log(this.FlowwersBy)` print ?

Answer (score 0):

Using async pipe with the *NgFor directive will help as the data coming back is an observable and not a property of type array.

Answer (score 0):

its better to use Async pipe and map instead of Subscripe as below:

HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="(FlowwersBy | async) as flowers">
  <li  *ngFor="let Flowwer of flowers" class="list-group-item" >
  {{ Flowwer }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Component:

```
ngOnInit() {
// Once component loads, get user's data to display on profile
 this.FlowwersBy = this.authService.getProfile()
 .map(profile=>profile.user.FlowwersBy)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li  *ngFor="let Flowwer of FlowwersBy; let i = index" class="list-group-item" >
      {{ Flowwer[i] }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```